How to handle empty input for RoBERTa text classification model?
I'm working on a text classification task using a fine-tuned RoBERTa model. My model takes text inputs and classifies them into predefined categories. However, I'm unsure how to handle cases where the input text is empty (i.e., an empty string or just whitespace).
Specifically:

What is the expected behavior of a RoBERTa model when given an empty input?
Should I implement a separate check for empty inputs before passing them to the model?
If I need to handle empty inputs separately, what's the best practice? Return a default classification, a special "empty input" category, or something else?
Are there any potential issues or unexpected behaviors I should be aware of when dealing with empty inputs in RoBERTa or similar transformer-based models?

I'd appreciate insights from those who have experience with RoBERTa or similar models in production environments. Thanks in advance!
